# How is this done. Javascript?

Tags: javascript, navigation, scroll

http://www.dennys.com

I'm wondering how the top navigation was programmed, From the source code I see javascript but I am hoping someone could recommend a resource / tutorial in learning how they built both the top navigation and the siding feature.

Many thanks.

Comment: just google "jquery slideshow html content", that'll take a lot of work, but looking through some available plugins should get you moving in the right direction

Comment: For better or for worse, I have never seen a web site design anything like that.  Whatever else you can say, someone put a lot of work into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt anyone has written a tutorial on how Denny's made a website.

But through some playing in the console, I found they use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which comes with many effects. To bring the navigation down, they probably use something like..

```
$('#navigation-button').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#navigation').slideDown();
});
```

I have something similar set up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tylermwashburn/yftTX/).

Don't use any of that code directly. It's just quickly written garbage. It'd need quite a bit of tweeking for production.

Comment: I agree that no one has written a tutorial on the Denny's site.  Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate Path.js ( https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs ) as the url's suggest they are using it.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with javascript/jquery. Create a main div with fixed witdh where you put all your pages (menu, home, etc) and overflow:hidden. Then, with jquery's plugin Animate slide the position of the div's content.

Answer (score 0):

Search for jquery controls. There are several available on the net free of charge which help you get this functionality.